# Google map keeps positioning itself to Los Atlos

Tags: android, cordova, google-maps-api-3, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Hi i have been trying to place a marker at my current location but the below code keeps reverting to Los Atlos, if i take out the marker it will locate my position, how do i get the marker to work?

```
Ext.define('FirstApp.view.Mapd',{
extend:'Ext.Panel',
    xtype:'maps',


     config : {
        fullscreen: true,
        layout: 'fit',
       title:'Map',
        iconCls:'map',

        items: [{
            xtype:  'map',

            mapOptions : {
               useCurrentLocation: true,
                zoom : 12,
                mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                navigationControl: true,
                navigationControlOptions: {
                    style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.DEFAULT
                }
            },

            listeners: {


                maprender: function(comp, map) {
                   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                   map : map,
                   position : map.center,
                   title : "Me",
                   animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
                       });

                    setTimeout(function() {
                          map.panTo(map.center);
                    }, 1000);
                }
            }
        }]
    }
})
```

Comment: You need to actually include the piece of code that sets the marker and location. That seems to be missing.

Answer (score 0):

Your order of instruction is all wrong… you need to follow the order below ::

1. Find your current location & update your currentLocation to that position by calling the geo method as below :

   ```
   mapOptions : { . . . 
         center : center
         zoom : 15
   },

   geo:new Ext.util.GeoLocation({

           autoUpdate:true,
           maximumAge: 0,
           timeout:2000,
           listeners:{
               locationupdate: function(geo) {
                   center = new google.maps.LatLng(geo.latitude, geo.longitude);
                   if (map.rendered)
                       map.update(center)
                   else
                       map.on('activate', map.onUpdate, map, {single: true, data: center});
               },
               locationerror: function (geo,bTimeout, bPermissionDenied, bLocationUnavailable, message) {
                   if(bLocationUnavailable){
                       alert('yayyyyour Current Location is Unavailable on this device');
                   }
                   else if (bPermissionDenied){
                       alert('Location capabilities have been disabled on this device.');
                   }      
               }
           }
       });
   ```
2. Add a maprender event to your listeners of the map object, here you can add the map marker.
   Once the step above is done, then your map is finally centered on your currentLocation perfectly (without any error case arising), then you create your marker object, and set its location to the center of the map object (since we have already centered the object to our current location, that means the marker is now at our current location)

   ```
   maprender : function(comp, map){
               var pos1;
               pos1 = new google.maps.LatLng(lats, longs);
               pos = pos1;
               var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    . . . .
               });
               map.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID);

               setTimeout( function(){map.panTo (pos);} , 1000);
           }
   ```

Comment: Hi i was trying to implement your solution but unfortunately i am getting an error as follows: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'on'  Any idea what this could be?